Буферизация видео, прогресс
https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/MediaPlayerEvents.html#event:BUFFER_LEVEL_UPDATED
Повесил событие на видео, в консоль выводит информацию следующего рода
bufferLevel: 33.109297
mediaType: "video"
streamId: "0"
type: "bufferLevelUpdated"

Не понимаю значение которое выдает bufferLevel. Как будто бы произвольные числа.
К примеру, видео играет на 10 секунде, значение bufferLevel:6
Что за формула, при помощи которой можно получить процент, то есть длину ползунка которые отображает буффер.??

Длину ползунка можно получить с помощью свойства video.currentTime(). А bufferlevel указывает на числовое значение текущего семпла, очередь которого наступила воспроизводиться. А Ваше событие срабатывает соответственно каждый раз, как только это значение меняется.
